# how to pass data in vuejs using axios header

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-cli

I'm having a difficult time with a form that I made, the methods script I wrote using axios header is not working at all, it's not showing any response. here is the script

```
methods: {
selesai() {
  let vm = this;
  vm.spinner = true;
  axios
    .post(
      ipBackend + "/admin/create",
      {
        createNewUser: this.formInput
      },
      {
        headers: {
          accesstoken: localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      }
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      vm.spinner = false;
      this.$router.push({ path: "/profilkonselor" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {});
},
```

},

I already bind the button with an event on the template, am I doing that wrong or something that I miss?

Comment: You can also try reading the error message...

Comment: somehow there's no error message, i already console.log the response, but it seems the function is not running when i pressed the button

Comment: I prefer debugger over console log - but i will not guess whats wrong, you have to verify each step. Currently you silent out errors.

Comment: You should add more info about the issue. For example what is going on in your template where you call this method

Answer (score 0):

Did you config the axios in main.js correctly? like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
```

If you did, you should use it like `this.$axios.post()`

Comment: yes i did, and the i just tried using $axios the result still the same

Comment: I read the comments above. You mean you add a console.log in the function, but it still no print. I think you hasn't bind the function to the button.